# Good sheet - Show cell value with max total value on multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets

i want to show the best time with max total likes within date range (weekly)
This is what i got so far
`=unique(FILTER(C2:C30,B2:B30>=G2,B2:B30<=H2))`

**Sample Table/Data**

| Date | time | likes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| June 1 | 2:00pm | 431 |
| June 2 | 3:00am | 450 |
| June 1 | 3:00pm | 222 |
| June 3 | 5:00am | 145 |
| June 4 | 7:00am | 251 |
| June 6 | 5:00am | 415 |

**Expected result/table**

| Week | Best Time |
| --- | --- |
| June 1 - June 6 | 3:00pm |
| June 7 - June 14 | 2:0am |
| June 15 - June 21 | 7:00pm |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWmeD.jpg)

Comment: 1) In the "expected result", the number of days in the date ranges are: 6, 8 and 7. Would you please explain how this is determined, and how it can be built-in into a formula. 2) Your same and expected results are brief, unlike the image which covers most of a month; it would be more helpful to supply the sample data in table form, AND supply the expected results for _that_ data.